# Scite bc5.5 ошибка обработки русскоязычных комментариев

Tags: c, borland

Почему если перед кодом языка С поставить комментарии, то сбивается кодировка и выдаются крякозябры? Редактор Scite, компилятор bc5.5
Если убрать коммент, то выдает нормальные русские буквы.

Comment: Если Вы пишете "перед кодом", то это значит, что Вы ставите два слеша? Но это не совсем коментарий в С.

к слову, bc5.5 - это очень древний компилятор, ему 17 лет. Смените.

Comment: Скорее всего для основного текста и комментариев указан разный шрифт, и тот который для комментариев не поддерживает кириллицу. Нужно покопаться в настроечных файлах SciTe и поменять шрифт комментариев.